# Скачивание файлов на компьютер пользователя

Tags: файлы, php

Всем привет! Такая проблема! На `web`-сервере имеется файлы, которые пользователю нужно скачать себе! Но нет что бы браузер предлагал скачать как, или куда! А что бы автоматически скачался файл на компьютер пользователя.

P.S 
Пользователь сам в настройках обозначит путь где должен сохраниться файл!

Comment: такого не должно быть. Захочет пользователь - сам настроит каталог по умолчанию. А не захочет - это его личное дело.

Автоматическое скачивания - это похоже на вирусы.

Comment: Ну да! Я конечно  вирусы не пишу! На работе стоят на том что бы автоматически всё было! В плоть до скачивания файла.

Comment: Просто думал кто нить с этим сталкивался!

Comment: Хром, ФФ это делает по-умолчанию автоматически.
Многие другие браузеры выводят диалог.

Comment: значит нужно менять работу. Либо писать отдельное приложение. Оно сможет делать все как нужно.

Сам по себе браузеры такого функционала избегают. И если удается найти такое, то это считается критическим багом и, обычно, исправляется.

Я знаю, что многие верят, что html5 - наше будущее, но я думаю, это скоро завершиться:)

Comment: @chambo, браузер так не умеет (а если умел бы - я бы автору браузера лицо помял), пишите десктопную прогу. Если в голове только пхп - юзайте [winbinder](http://winbinder.org/) какой-нибудь, если под винду.

Comment: Ладно всем спасибо!

Comment: > браузер так не умеет (а если умел бы - я бы автору браузера лицо помял)

Составляющим ТЗ `Автоматизаторам...` на заметку.

Comment: Как вариант - написать расширение для браузера.

Comment: @lampa: подобное расширение означало бы зияющую дыру в безопасности браузера.

Comment: @VladD, ну вообще если это что-то локально-сетевое для нужд компании, с жестким URL/IP - хм, почему бы и нет. Опасна только подмена DNS вирусняком, написанным специально под это дополнение %)